# How to make a 3D Mesh in RGL with shade3d or wire3d using tmesh3d in R

Tags: r, mesh, rgl

I have some data which I have collected.

It consists of Vertices and then Triangles which I have made using a meshing software.

I am able to use R with

trimesh(triangles, vertices)

to make a nice mesh plot.

But can't figure out how to use  RGL to make an interactive plot that I can view, and I can't work out how to colour the faces of the mesh based on a different value in the data frame.

here are the vertices  in a data frame. x, y, z are the coordinates of the nodes/points (nn)

```
'data.frame':   23796 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ nn : int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ x  : num  39.5 70.8 49 83.5 -16 ...
 $ y  : num  28.2 -2.97 -25.67 -9.1 -39.75 ...
 $ z: num  160 158 109 121 188 ...
 $ uni: num  3.87 6.64 5.02 4.48 1.91 ...
 $ bi : num  0.749 0.784 1.045 0.935 0.733 ...




nn  x   y   z   uni bi
0   39.527  28.202  160.219 3.86942 0.74871
1   70.804  -2.966  157.578 6.64361 0.78373
2   48.982  -25.674 109.022 5.02491 1.0451
3   83.514  -9.096  120.988 4.47977 0.9348
4   -16.04  -39.749 188.467 1.90873 0.73286
5   74.526  -3.096  174.347 8.4263  0.70594
6   54.93   -56.347 151.496 7.53334 2.17128
7   56.936  -20.131 186.177 7.16118 1.44875
8   -14.627 -47.1   162.185 2.13939 0.70887
9   38.207  -59.201 147.993 5.83457 4.32971
10  50.645  -32.04  110.418 5.3741  1.14543
```

The triangles for the vertices are

```
'data.frame':   47602 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ X  : int  3435 3161 18424 13600 1564 21598 21283 1171 51 9331 ...
 $ Y  : int  19658 17204 17467 19721 10099 19018 11341 2723 15729 5851 ...
 $ Z  : int  2764 9466 16955 2669 10091 21205 18399 20833 15865 9106 ...


X   Y   Z
3435    19658   2764
3161    17204   9466
18424   17467   16955
13600   19721   2669
1564    10099   10091
21598   19018   21205
21283   11341   18399
1171    2723    20833
51  15729   15865
9331    5851    9106
310 3513    9121
5651    11928   15468  
8594    2295    6852
22725   22636   11114
```

I need to make this into a mesh as I can in trimesh, but with RGL and I need to colour the faces of the mesh based on a scale of uni, where <0.5 is red, 0/5-1/5 is orange and >1.5 is green

[It looks something like this in trimesh but how to i do it in RGL for R, WITH COLOURING BASED ON VALUE ON UNI in the first data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3qk7.png)

Comment: when i try shade3d( tmesh3d(vert,face)) I get
Error in x$vb[1, x$it] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: is it something to do with homogeneity?  i.e.  i have non homogenous data in that the vertices data frame is smaller than the indices? and if so how do i solve it?

Comment: I don't understand the format of your triangles dataframe.  It should be a matrix each row containing indices into the columns of the vertices matrix corresponding to which vertex is in which triangle.  Maybe if you post a complete example which people can run someone will show you how to do it.

Comment: How do I post a whole data frame(s). Nodes are 20000+ rows and vertices 40000+. The vertices is actually a data frame for each node

Comment: Don't post all of your data.  Come up with a simple example that only needs a few triangles in the mesh, and post that.  `dput()` is good for posting structured data.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, starting with two dataframes.

```
> library(rgl)
> vertices
   x  y  z
1  1 -1  1
2  1 -1 -1
3  1  1 -1
4  1  1  1
5 -1 -1  1
6 -1 -1 -1
7 -1  1 -1
8 -1  1  1
> triangles
  T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6 T7 T8 T9 T10 T11 T12
1  5  5  1  1  2  2  6  6  8   8   1   1
2  1  4  2  3  6  7  5  8  4   3   6   5
3  4  8  3  4  7  3  8  7  3   7   2   6
```

You need matrices to deal with `tmesh3d`. A row of `1`'s must be added to the table of vertices.

```
verts <- rbind(t(as.matrix(vertices)),1)
trgls <- as.matrix(triangles)
tmesh <- tmesh3d(verts, trgls)
```

Now you can plot the mesh:

```
wire3d(tmesh)
```

[image]

About colors, you have to associate one color to each triangle:

```
tmesh$material <- list(color=rainbow(ncol(trgls)))
wire3d(tmesh)
```

[image]

```
> shade3d(tmesh)
```

[image]

## UPDATE 2019-03-09

The newest version of `rgl` (0.100.18) allows different interpretation of the material colors.

You can assign a color to each face:

```
vertices <- as.matrix(vertices)
triangles <- as.matrix(triangles)
mesh1 <- tmesh3d(
  vertices = t(vertices),
  indices = triangles,
  homogeneous = FALSE,
  material = list(color = rainbow(ncol(triangles)))
)
shade3d(mesh1, meshColor = "faces")
```

[image]

or assign a color to each vertex:

```
mesh2 <- tmesh3d(
  vertices = t(vertices),
  indices = triangles,
  homogeneous = FALSE,
  material = list(color = rainbow(nrow(vertices)))
)
shade3d(mesh2, meshColor = "vertices")
```

[image]